# Return a 2dim array from C back into R

Tags: r, c

I´m using Rstudio, but because of performance reasons I have to call a set of functions in C code. So far I´m using .C() to call the C code. I want to return a 2 dimensional array, but I don´t know the size before calling the C code. What I read about .C() suggested that I can´t use it for my problem because the only way I can "return" something is by passing an argument to .C() and changing it in the C code. E.g. I shouldn´t be able to pass a matrix or 2 dimensional array onto .C() and change it´s size within the C code right?

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what RStudio is exactly. However, it seems that they provide a way to access/modify R object in C++ ( https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio ). Is it what you're trying to use? It seems they have examples on how to perform some transformation on object and even return the result of the transformation via a C++ function. 

PS : C++ is based on C.

Comment: Didn´t see that one yet. Thanks a lot, will look into it